# Proving the $L^\infty$ metric on $C([0,1])$ dominates the $L^1$ one, but not vice versa

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm considering two different metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on the set $C([0,1])$ on continuous functions from $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. These metrics are as follows.
\begin{align*}
d_1(f_1, f_2) & = \max\limits_{t \in [0,1]} |f_1 (t) - f_2 (t)| \\
d_2 (f_1, f_2) & = \int_{t \in [0,1]} |f_1 (t) - f_2 (t)| \; dt. 
\end{align*}
The exercise I'm trying to solve is:

> Show that the metric $d_1$ dominates the metric $d_2$ but not vice versa.

Here is my attempt.

> To show that $d_1$ dominates $d_2$, we must show there exists $C \geq 0$ such that for all $f_1, f_2 \in C([0,1])$, we have
> $$
> d_2 (f_1, f_2) \leq C d_1 (f_1, f_2).
> $$
> Let $f_1, f_2 \in C([0,1])$. As integrals preserve order, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> d_2 (f_1, f_2) & = \int_{t \in [0,1]} |f_1 (t) - f_2 (t)| \; dt \\
> & \leq \int_{t \in [0,1]} \max\limits_{t \in [0,1]} \{|f_1 (t) - f_2 (t)|\} \; \\
> & \max\limits_{t \in [0,1]} \{|f_1 (t) - f_2 (t)|\} t \bigg|_0^1 \\
> & = \max\limits_{t \in [0,1]} \{|f_1 (t) - f_2 (t)|\} \\
> & = d_1 (f_1, f_2). 
> \end{align*}
> So $d_2$ dominates $d_1$ with $C = 1$.

I'm less certain about my approach to (b), but here is my attempt, based on a helpful comment.

> To show that $d_2$ does not dominate $d_1$, I believe I need to find a counterexample which satisfies: for all $C \geq 0$, there exist $f_1, f_2 \in C([0,1])$ such that
> $$
> d_1 (f_1, f_2) > C d_2 (f_1, f_2). 
> $$
> Fix $C \geq 0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $N > C - 1$. Then set
> $$
> f_1 (t) = 0, \; f_2 (t) = t^N.
> $$
> Then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ since constant functions are continuous, as are monomial functions, so $f_1, f_2 \in C([0,1])$. We have:
> \begin{align*}
> d_1 (f_1, f_2) & = \max\limits_{t \in [0,1]} |0 - t^N| = \max\limits_{t \in [0,1]} t^N = 1^N = 1 \\ 
> d_2 (f_1, f_2) & = \int_{t \in [0,1]} |0 - t^N| = \int_{t \in [0,1]} t^N = \frac{t^{N+1}}{N+1} \bigg |_0^1 = \frac{1}{N+1}. 
> \end{align*}
> Then we have
> \begin{align*}
> 1 > \frac{C}{N+1} \iff N + 1 > C \iff N > C - 1,
> \end{align*}
> so $d_1 (f_1, f_2) > C d_2 (f_1, f_2)$.

Comment: How about you set $f_1(x) = 0$ and $f_2(x) = x^n$ and look at what happens when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to introduce uniform/pointwise convergence of functions, as this hasn't yet been defined in the lecture notes I'm working through.

Comment: @JosephCamacho I think I took the same approach you recommended. How does this above attempt look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving one metric on $\mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ dominates another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341557/proving-one-metric-on-mathcalc0-1-mathbbr-dominates-another) (looks like someone from the same class maybe.)

Comment: (fyi I edited your english- matrices -> metrics, and conditions -> continuous. Attempt looks good)